# setting cookie in custom webpart

Tags: development, web-part

I have a webpart and I need to set a cookie and read write from/to this cookie.

I tried to read the cookie using `Request.Cookies["Cookiename"]` and setting the cookie using `Response.Cookies["Cookiename"]` but it's not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading a cookie should be using the correct request method!

**read:**

```
string getval = null;
if (Page.Request.Cookies["YourCookieName"] != null)
{
    getval = Page.Request.Cookies["YourCookieName"].Value;
}
```

its as simple as that ;)

for sharepoint and webparts its `Page.Request` that we use instead of `Request.Cookies` as that refers to `HttpRequest.Cookies`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx

when writing you can do:

```
Response.Cookies
```

like so:

**Create:**

```
HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie("test");
c.Value = "testing";

HttpRequest response = Page.Request;
response.Cookies.Add(c);
```

**write:**

```
string setval = "welcome";
if (Page.Request.Cookies["YourCookieName"] != null)
{
        Page.Request.Cookies["YourCookieName"].Value = setval;
}
```

create two methods, one for get and one for set, it should have two strings. One for the cookie name and the other for the value (string int to return or set)

```
    private void setCookie(string val, string cookiename)
    {
        if (Page.Request.Cookies[cookiename] != null)
        {
            Page.Request.Cookies[cookiename].Value = val;
        }
    }

    private string getCookie(string val, string cookiename)
    {
        if (Page.Request.Cookies[cookiename] != null)
        {
             val = Page.Request.Cookies[cookiename].Value ;
        }

        return val;
    }


    private string createCookie(string cookiename,string val)
    {
        HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie(cookiename);
        if (val != null || val != string.empty)
        {
             c.Value = val;

             HttpRequest response = Page.Request;
             response.Cookies.Add(c);   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How to create cookie:

```
HttpCookie createcookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName");
createcookie.Value = "true";
createcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(noDays);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(createcookie);
```

Read cookie:

```
 string mycookieVal;
    HttpCookie readCookie= HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieName"];
    if (readCookie!= null)
    {
      mycookieVal = readCookie.Value;
    }
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c38a0c55-728c-426b-9f56-0f54d66dc80c/create-a-cookie-in-a-sp-web-part

Comment: I am already doing that, the cookie is there, but it's giving me null value after I load the page again

Comment: Have u tested it in different browsers ?